# Continuously extend this function to the unit sphere.

Tags: limits, vectors, 3d

Given a nonzero vector $u$, I can define the map
$$
f_{u} : S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \\
f_{u}(x) = \frac{u-(u\cdot x)x}{({(u \cdot x)^2}/(u\cdot u))-1}
$$
which is well-defined everywhere except when $u$ and $x$ are parallel. So, I have two questions:

1. Does $f_{u}$ have limits at those two points where it is not well-defined, and what are those limits?
2. Is there a simple geometric interpretation of what $f_{u}$ does to the unit sphere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $f_{cu}(x)=cf_u(x)$ so you may as well let $u\in S^2$.

To see what the function is doing, take the great circle $C$ containing $\frac{u}{|u|},x\in S^2$

Set the coordinates $u=(|u|,0),, x=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ so that $u\cdot x=|u|\cos\theta$.

Then

\begin{eqnarray}
f_u(x)&=\frac{(1,0)-\cos\theta(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)}{\cos^2\theta-1}\cdot |u|\\
      &=\left(-1,\cot\theta\right)\cdot|u|
\end{eqnarray}

Which is a 'vertical' line. So the function maps $S^2$ onto a plane.

Here is a geometrical illustration of how the mapping works.

[image: Geometrical illustration of map]

Addendum: Note that $f$ is discontinuous at $(\pm1,0)$.

Comment: Indeed, $f_u$ is stereographic projection onto the tangent space $T_uS^2$ and then translated by $-2u$, or equivalently reflected across the plane $u^\perp$, to $T_{-u}S^2$.